# How to remaster a retro game's graphics?

Tags: 2d, graphics, textures, tiles, art

I want to remake an old game, which graphics is pretty old (1980s game), and I want to make a "HD version" of it. Of course, the game will have an "old graphics" setting, but I want to remaster the old sprites, tiles. How can I do it? Is there any program to it, or the whole graphics should be redrawn?

Comment: You mean, is there a program that will [Enhance!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUFkb0d1kbU)? No probably not.

Comment: I think what you want is in the frames of a remake. you have to have different game assets/resources. [knight lore remake](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mL2wwosBxbs&feature=related) [knight lore original](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1s7kexSrHE&feature=related)

Comment: Side-note:  Games from the 1980s are still under copyright (and presumably will be for at least another 50 years or so).  Distributing their graphics or derivative works of their graphics would be considered copyright violation in most of the world.  There are also trademark concerns.  It's definitely worth seeking the advice of an IP attorney in your part of the world for the particular laws which apply to you in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

There do exist some pretty impressive methods for scaling up pixel art, it's not bullet proof, but some of it could at least prove to save some time in the process of a manual retouch: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling

Do remember, as long as you don't have a computer made from pure scifitanium none of them are going to add anything beyond what already was in the picture, up-scaled figures may seem oddly detail lacking.